# use the_posts_pagination(); without title

Tags: wordpress, pagination

When using the_posts_pagination ([see codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination)) the pagination displays a title "post navigation".

Is it possible to turn this off?

For example using something like:

```
the_posts_pagination( array(
    'title'              => '', // this should hide the title
    'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'next_text'          => __( 'Next', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( '', 'nieuwedruk' ) . ' </span>',
) );
```

Answer (score 15):

There is "screen_reader_text" property that should help you

```
the_posts_pagination( array(
    'screen_reader_text' => ' ', 
    'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'next_text'          => __( 'Next', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( '', 'nieuwedruk' ) . ' </span>',
) );
```

Note: Hence the space between the single quotes.

Comment: Hi @asgu, thanks for the reply. However that doesn't seem to change it though.

Comment: Adding a space between the single quotes seems to do the trick.

Comment: What about SEO? H2 is still in page

Answer (score 2):

While searching for a solution i've found this link to be the most relative but not a complete solution for my situation. Above answer will cause a warning when validating your HTML with W3C.

I've found a way to completely remove the heading by adding an action which will remove the h2 tag with preg_replace(). Regex isn't my best job so if you have suggestions please let me now.

I've put the following action in my functions.php:

```
function sanitize_pagination($content) {
    // Remove role attribute
    $content = str_replace('role="navigation"', '', $content);

    // Remove h2 tag
    $content = preg_replace('#<h2.*?>(.*?)<\/h2>#si', '', $content);

    return $content;
}

add_action('navigation_markup_template', 'sanitize_pagination');
```

Above function will also remove the "role" attribute from the nav element (Causes W3C warning).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but for people wanting simple solution,
a simple CSS block would do the trick. No need to tweak php.

```
h2.screen-reader-text {
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
.post-navigation h2.screen-reader-text {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. It is still generating undesired HTML rubbish, which may not visible to users, but it is visible for search engines, bots, etc.